# Posicionar Columnas en el lugar de las filas con SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

Buen Día compañeros, soy nuevo en SQL, por lo mismo mi pregunta es sencilla, me pregunto si es posible en una consulta SQL posicionar las columnas de una tabla en la posición de las filas, he leído sobre las funciones PIVOT y UNPIVOT, pero no se de que manera aplicarlo.

mi situación es la siguiente, he hecho una consulta la cuál su resultado es el siguiente:

```
      |Total_Diezmos |Total_Ofrendas |  Total_Ingresos 
------+--------------+---------------+----------------
1     | 500          | 300           |     800
```

Ahora lo que quisiera como resultado es lo siguiente:

```
Totales_mensuales |  Sumatoria | 
------------------+------------+
Total_Diezmos     | 500        |  
Total_Ofrendas    | 300        |  
Total_Ingresos    | 800        |
```

Mi consulta es muy simple, solamente quisiera saber como posicionar los resultados de la manera deseada, mi código es el siguiente:

```
SELECT total_diezmos, total_ofrendas, total_ingresos FROM integracion_anual WHERE id_integracion_anual = 1
```

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos utilizas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé cuál es la estructura de tu tabla pero aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo.

```
CREATE TABLE Cuentas (Total_Diezmos int, Total_Ofrendas int,Total_Ingresos int);  
GO  
INSERT INTO Cuentas VALUES (500,300,800);  

GO  
-- Unpivot the table.  
SELECT Totales_mensuales, Sumatoria  
FROM   
   (SELECT Total_Diezmos, Total_Ofrendas, Total_Ingresos
   FROM Cuentas) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (Sumatoria FOR Totales_mensuales IN   
      (Total_Diezmos, Total_Ofrendas, Total_Ingresos)  
)AS unpvt;  
GO
```